# How to script enable VR in Unity 5.1

Tags: virtual-reality, unity

Unity 5.1 has integrated VR, its in the Build Player Settings as a checkbox. I want a startup scene that is not VR, then when the user starts it enables the VR camera. Can I do that?

Comment: I haven't tested this but it look like the support is in the API, check out this page.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRSettings.html

Answer (score 3):

> To enable VR for your game builds and the editor, set the “Virtual
>   Reality Supported” option in [Player Settings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html).

This means you can activate it via the PlayerSettings either via the UI or via Script.

```
PlayerSettings.virtualRealitySupported = true;
```

Unity wrote a manual about VR in general. 
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VROverview.html